# Frenet-Serret-Formula - confused about formulas about tangent vector?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

> I want to calculate the TNB for 
>   $$
>    c(t)=      \begin{pmatrix}
>         r \cdot \cos(t) \\
>        r \cdot \sin(t) \\
>         h \cdot  t\\
>         \end{pmatrix} r>0 , h\neq0
> $$

I'm confused about one thing:

Is it $T = \frac{\dot c(t)}{||\dot c(t)||}$ or just $ T=\dot c(t)$ ?

I guess that if it's $ T=\dot c(t)$ , then we need the condition $r^2+h^2=1$.
If so , would it suffices to norm the vector and then use the second formula ?
As
$$
   \dot c(t)=      \begin{pmatrix}
        -r \cdot \sin(t) \\
       r \cdot \cos(t) \\
        h \\
        \end{pmatrix} r>0 , h\neq0
$$
$\Rightarrow ||\dot c(t)||=\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$ but this hasn't necessary to be $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dot{c}(t)$ is tangent to $c(t)$, but is not in general a unit vector.
$$T=\frac{\dot{c}(t)}{||\dot{c}(t)||}$$
is the unit tangent vector. $T$ in the Frenet-Serret frame is the unit tangent vector.